# How to select the most recent records in a dataset in sql

Tags: sql, maxdate

I have a large dataset where we keep track of all revenue collected by client for each month. So each client gets a row for each month they were charged, resulting in a lot of rows. I am trying to find a way to pull the most recent record for each client.

Here is what i have:

| merchant name | Merchant id | revenue date | revenue amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fish | 1234 | 2022-03-01 | 200 |
| fish | 1234 | 2022-04-01 | 200 |
| fish | 1234 | 2022-05-01 | 200 |
| fish | 1234 | 2022-06-01 | 200 |
| dog | 5678 | 2022-01-01 | 200 |
| dog | 5678 | 2022-02-01 | 200 |
| dog | 5678 | 2022-03-01 | 200 |
| dog | 5678 | 2022-04-01 | 200 |
| cat | 1011 | 2022-10-01 | 200 |
| cat | 1011 | 2022-11-01 | 200 |

My desired result is:

| merchant name | Merchant id | revenue date | revenue amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fish | 1234 | 2022-06-01 | 200 |
| dog | 5678 | 2022-04-01 | 200 |
| cat | 1011 | 2022-11-01 | 200 |

I have tried this:

```
Select distinct
merchant_name,
merchant_id,
revenue_date,
revenue_amount
from table
where revenue_date=(select max(revenue_date) from table)
```

but that is only returning rows that match the maximum date listed (2022-11-01).

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What's the database? Easy in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

The general solution takes the form:

```
select *
from (
  select t.*, row_number() over(partition by merchant_name 
                                order by revenue_date desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Or... in PostgreSQL you can just do:

```
select distinct on (merchant_name) *
from t
order by merchant_name, revenue_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate answer (formatted for SQL Server):

```
--For each merchantID, find the latest date
WITH maxDates AS (
    SELECT 
    merchantID,
    MAX(revenueDate) revenueDate
    FROM @input
    GROUP BY merchantID
)

--Use the defined CTE to retrieve the rest of the columns
SELECT i.* 
FROM @input i 
INNER JOIN maxDates m ON i.merchantID=m.merchantID AND i.revenueDate=m.revenueDate
```